# Laravel: How to persist data between two different requests in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, state-management

I have a Laravel controller with two methods: **createOrder** and **getStatus**. In the create method, I'm trying to set a property `$orderId` to store an orderId value, and in the get method, I want to access and display this value using `dd($this->orderId)`.

```
class XXXPaymentController extends Controller
{
    protected $orderId;
    
    public function createOrder(){
         // ... create an $order
         $this->orderId = $order->id;
    }
    
    public function getStatus(){
          dd($this->orderId); // return null
    }
}
```

However, since Laravel creates a new instance of the controller for each request, the **getStatus** method returns null because it's a different instance.

This is specifically a payment request, and I need to persist the `$orderId` between these two methods. How can I achieve this in Laravel? Is there a recommended way to share data between methods in a controller for different requests?

Comment: Use cache for this - put value in method, then get in other method on second request.

Comment: @Maksim is cache or session okay for this?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. Session and cache are two most common ways. It depends what better suits business logic, but outcome is the same: stored data between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way of doing this will be by using laravel session helper.
On the first method, store the orderId like this

```
public function createOrder(){
     // ... create an $order
     session(['orderId' => $order->id]); 
}
```

And then on the second one, when you want to retrieve the previously stored order id

```
public function getStatus(){
      $orderId = session('orderId');
}
```

Note that if you want to pass a default value to the orderId on retrieval, you can transform the line like this :

```
$orderId = session('orderId', 'defaultValue'); // The default value can be of any type
```

PS: Sorry if I've made some grammatical mistake, English is not my main language.

Comment: Is this solutions really maintainable and testable ?

Answer (score 0):

besides session and cache, you can use a service class that you will inject into your controller's constructor, preserving the order_id.

This solution is more modular, and testable and follows good design principles by separating concerns related to managing the order_id into a dedicated service class.

This will also solve the issue of controller instances being recreated between requests, as the service maintains its state independently of the controller instance.

create an interface like this,

```
interface OrderIdServiceInterface
{
    public function storeOrderId(int $orderId);
    public function getOrderId();
}
```

Then create a service that will implement this service like below,

```
class OrderIdService implements OrderIdServiceInterface
{
    private $orderId;

    public function storeOrderId(int $orderId)
    {
        $this->orderId = $orderId;
    }

    public function getOrderId(): int
    {
        return $this->orderId;
    }
}
```

Then inject this service class into your controller in the constructor.

```
class XXXPaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $orderIdService;

    public function __construct(OrderIdServiceInterface $orderIdService)
    {
        $this->orderIdService = $orderIdService;
    }
    
    public function createOrder(){
         // ... create an $order
         $this->orderIdService->storeOrderId($order->id);
    }
    
    public function getStatus(){
       dd($this->orderIdService->getOrderId());
    }
}
```